# End method if textbox is empty?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-sdk-2.3

My tip calculator only works when the two text fields i have filled, i would like to have it display a message, and then keep the app from force closing...

Here is the java that i tried, but it doesn't work

```
  package tip.calculator;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;




public class TipCalculator extends Activity 
{

private Button enter;
EditText myEditField ;
EditText myEditField2;
float percentage = 0;
float percentageInp = 0;
float billAmount = 0;
double output = 0; 
String output1 = "";
Button clearButton ;
TextView textView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myEditField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentText);
    enter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    myEditField2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billText);
    clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearButton);


    enter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {

             TextView errors;
             textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             errors = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorText);    



             if((myEditField2 != null) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(myEditField2.getText().toString()))){


                percentageInp = Float.parseFloat(myEditField.getText().toString());
                billAmount = Float.parseFloat(myEditField2.getText().toString());

                percentage = ((float)percentageInp /100);

                output = (double)(billAmount * percentage);

                double result = output * 100;
                result = Math.round(result);
                result = result / 100;

                output1 = Double.toString(result);

                textView.setText(output1 + " $");

             } else{
                //Toast.makeToast(.....).show(); //Inform user about the error
             }

        }
    });

    clearButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            percentage = 0;
            output = 0;
            output1 = "";

            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.errorText);
            textView.setText("");

            TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentText);
            textView2.setText("");

            TextView textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.billText);
            textView3.setText("");


            TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView1.setText("");


            percentageInp = 0;
            billAmount = 0;

            myEditField.clearComposingText();
            myEditField2.clearComposingText();

        }


    });
}
}
```

here is the stack trace and updated java is above

```
08-01 21:24:17.824: E/AndroidRuntime(19302): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 21:24:17.824: E/AndroidRuntime(19302): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
08-01 21:24:17.824: E/AndroidRuntime(19302):    at tip.calculator.TipCalculator$1.onClick(TipCalculator.java:48)
08-01 21:24:17.824: E/AndroidRuntime(19302):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3620)
08-01 21:24:17.824: E/AndroidRuntime(19302):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14292)
08-01 21:24:17.824: E/AndroidRuntime(19302):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-01 21:24:17.824: E/AndroidRuntime(19302):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-01 21:24:17.824: E/AndroidRuntime(19302):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 21:24:17.824: E/AndroidRuntime(19302):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
08-01 21:24:17.824: E/AndroidRuntime(19302):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 21:24:17.824: E/AndroidRuntime(19302):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 21:24:17.824: E/AndroidRuntime(19302):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
08-01 21:24:17.824: E/AndroidRuntime(19302):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
08-01 21:24:17.824: E/AndroidRuntime(19302):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the text field for null is not a problem. But you definitely must check the text for empty string and null . android.text.TextUtis.isEmpty() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence) is handy in this case. Also you must ensure that string entered is a float. So you must also do  a try catch to capture any parse error and set the android:inputType property of the textfield to numberDecimal to ensure the input is a float.

Thus:

1. In your layout, add property `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` , to ensure that you user can only input valid decimal number.
2. Do all the safety checks

```
    if((myEditField2 != null) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(myEditField2.getText().toString()))){
        //use you data here
    } else{
       Toast.makeToast(.....).show() //Inform user about the error
    }
```

If you do 1 you may not need to surround  `Float.parseFloat(myEditField.getText().toString())`  with a try-catch for a `NumberFormatException`

Comment: this is a little confusing, can you break it down a little for me - thanks

Comment: Can you post your layout? It look likes one of the ids is not pointing  to the text field but rather to the layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you would to check that String in edit text is not empty,you can use:

```
if(et.getText().toString() != null){

}
```